# Is it possible to place a UIPageControl above UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Hello I'm been racking my head all day. I have about 5 months worth of iOS experience. What I'm trying to do is place a `UIPageControl` view above a `UIScrollView`. Here is my code...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    //self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[self window_width], [self window_height])];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([self window_width], [self window_height])];
    [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];

    self.pageControl = [[FXPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [self window_width], [self window_height])];
    self.pageControl.dotShape = FXPageControlDotShapeCircle;
    self.pageControl.selectedDotShape = FXPageControlDotShapeCircle;
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = [self.childViewControllers count];
    self.pageControl.selectedDotSize = 30.0;
    self.pageControl.dotSize = 30.0;
    self.pageControl.defersCurrentPageDisplay = YES;
    self.pageControl.dotSpacing = 50.0;
    self.pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}
```

I tried interchanging adding the `SubViews` of `ScrollView` over `pageControl` and that just made the `scrollview` disappear.

Answer (score 0):

you can divide the space of your view separately for pageview and scrollview or you can add the pageview controller in the scroll view and adjust the content hight of the scrollview.

your over lapping the view with one another.

Comment: Sounds like dividing the space of my view separately is the solution I'm looking for. My question now is how do I go about doing that with code?

Comment: can you please point to an example of dividing space for your view?

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIPageControl above UIScrollView to the self.view by the below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
 //self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
 self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [self window_width], [self window_height])];
 [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([self window_width], [self window_height])];
  [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
  [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
  [self.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
  [self.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
  [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];

  self.pageControl = [[FXPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [self window_width], [self window_height])];
  self.pageControl.dotShape = FXPageControlDotShapeCircle;
  self.pageControl.selectedDotShape = FXPageControlDotShapeCircle;
  self.pageControl.numberOfPages = [self.childViewControllers count];
  self.pageControl.selectedDotSize = 30.0;
  self.pageControl.dotSize = 30.0;
  self.pageControl.defersCurrentPageDisplay = YES;
  self.pageControl.dotSpacing = 50.0;
  self.pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
  [self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];
}
```

This code adds UIScrollView to self.view and after that it adds UIPageControl to self.view

or else you can add

> [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pageContol];

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although what I'm going for is placing the position of the UIPageControl view on top of the UIScrollView. So instead of the default look of ScrollView over the pagecontrol dots. I would like the dots to be on top of the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. I don't know if this is good practice though. Anyways the code below places the UIPageControl over the UIScrollView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [self.scrollView setNeedsDisplay];

    self.pageControl = [[FXPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 90, [self window_width], 50)];
    self.pageControl.dotShape = FXPageControlDotShapeCircle;
    self.pageControl.selectedDotShape = FXPageControlDotShapeCircle;
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = [self.childViewControllers count];
    self.pageControl.selectedDotSize = 30.0;
    self.pageControl.dotSize = 30.0;
    self.pageControl.defersCurrentPageDisplay = YES;
    self.pageControl.dotSpacing = 50.0;
    self.pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.pageControl.selectedDotColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x54b97f);
    self.pageControl.dotColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}
```